# Is there a SAX way to loop through OpenXML rows?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, sax, openxml-sdk

I'm parsing a large file using the SAX approach offered  on:
[Parsing and Reading Large Excel Files with the Open XML SDK](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_jones/archive/2010/05/27/parsing-and-reading-large-excel-files-with-the-open-xml-sdk.aspx)

This is my modified version (only getting the row number for simplicity)

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("BigFile.xlsx", true))
{
    WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
    WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();

    OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
    String rowNum;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
        {
            if (reader.HasAttributes)
                rowNum = reader.Attributes.First(a => a.LocalName == "r").Value
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this loops through every item/cell/column/whatnot and only acts when the element type is Row.

Is there a SAX way to loop only through the rows and not every item in the worksheet?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is to use the `Skip()` and `ReadNextSibling()` methods of the reader...

```
 using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open("BigFile.xlsx", true))
 {
     WorkbookPart workbookPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;
     WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.WorksheetParts.First();
     OpenXmlReader reader = OpenXmlReader.Create(worksheetPart);
     String rowNum;
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         if (reader.ElementType == typeof(Row))
         {
             do
             {
                 if (reader.HasAttributes)
                     rowNum = reader.Attributes.First(a => a.LocalName == "r").Value;

             } while (reader.ReadNextSibling()); // Skip to the next row
             break; // We just looped through all the rows so no need to continue reading the worksheet
         }

         if (reader.ElementType != typeof(Worksheet)) // Dont' want to skip the contents of the worksheet
             reader.Skip(); // Skip contents of any node before finding the first row.
     }
}
```

Comment: how to get each cellvalue in the rows in order.Basically i want to read using openxmlreader and write using openxmlwriter.